# Joint CDF of random variables vis-a-vis that of their order statistics

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function, order-statistics

Suppose $\{X_i\}_{i\in 1\ldots n}$ are $n$ independent, non-identically distributed RV's. Let $X_i \sim f_i(x) \mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}$, where $f_i$ is the $i$-th parent supported on $[0,1]$.

I am confused between two notions: the joint CDF $F(X_1,\ldots, X_n)$ and the joint cdf of the **order statistics** $F(X_{(1)},\ldots,X_{(n)})$.

> Are they related at all, as they do for iid RVs? If so, how?

It seems to me that over that subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ on which the tuple $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is nondecreasing (a simplex), the two cdfs would coincide. But then, $F(X_{1\ldots n})$ is a product of parent CDFs wherever it is defined, and is easy to compute. On the other hand, $F(X_{(1\ldots n)})$ has an expression driven by the [permanent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bapat%E2%80%93Beg_theorem) of an $n\times n$ matrix, and is thus intractable. What am I missing?

Comment: Look at this https://books.google.com/books?id=bdhzFXg6xFkC&pg=PA95&lpg=PA95&dq=order+statistics+non-iid&source=bl&ots=OcG_m-xaXg&sig=Ac7mEpg-IwOx6yOoUmG8xWzlv48&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQ6N6dyJvKAhVM0hoKHXU1AboQ6AEINjAD#v=onepage&q=order%20statistics%20non-iid&f=false .

Comment: I've been through that section, but my understanding of the question is still foggy.